# sharepoint 2010 Profile editor generated html

Tags: user-profile

`<SPSWC:ProfileEditor id="ProfileEditor" runat="server" />` generates tables, which are not very accessible for blind people.
It would be preferable to have labels and inputs
Would it be possible to generate something else than the tables?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ASP.NET custom control adapters to do this, here's an example for doing it with WebPartZones, but the principle is the same:

http://blog.sharepoint.ch/2007/12/webpartzone-adapter.html

Also, here's a hint from Waldek Mastykarz in anticipation of any problems you might have: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-control-adapters/